# Batch files to run other batch files in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to use a single batch file to open multiple cmd windows and run commands in them.

Here's what I have now:

```
start cmd.exe /k "grunt watch"
start cmd.exe /k "nodemon server.js"
```

It creates 2 new cmd windows and it seems to be running the commands. However, there's nothing displayed in the cmd windows. There's usually messages displayed for `grunt watch` and `nodemon server.js`. How can I open the 2 windows and still display messages?

Comment: have you consider putting the commands in a separate .bat files and call them?

Comment: That should work; I can't think of any reason why a batch script would behave differently after being launched in that way.

Comment: Ditto. You're overlooking something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Fawzan said, you can create two different batch files, so that each can open one program. I have tested this and it seems to function how you want it to function, you must run `grunt.bat` first:

**grunt.bat**

```
@echo OFF
echo Let's run Grunt watch
grunt watch
start cmd.exe /k nodemon.bat
pause
```

**nodemon.bat**

```
@echo OFF
echo "Let's run Nodemon server.js"
nodemon server.js
pause
```

Hope this works for you